# Help reconnecting light to existing ceiling box wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I had to replace an improperly used plastic ceiling box with a metal box to correctly ground existing old armored cable. I thought I took a picture of the box before but I don't have it so I'm having trouble reconnecting the light. Off of this box are:

- Single pole switch for overhead bedroom light
- Two 3 way switches for bedroom closet and hallway light (both go on and off at same time)

With how it is currently wired, the single pole switch/light are working and the closet light is working with the 3 way switches. I am not sure how to reconnect the hallway light so that it also goes on/off with the closet light and 3 way.

Thanks in advance.

This is where the hallway fixture goes:
[image: ceiling box]

On the left is the bedroom overhead light. On the right is the 3 way for the hallway light and closet light (these are supposed to come on at the same time):
[image: 2-gang switch box]

The other 3 way for the hallway and closet light:
[image: 1-gang switch box]

Comment: You've done well to include a picture! (Amazing how many people don't.) It would be even _more_ helpful if you could label the wiring we can see.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes involved please?

Comment: I added photos of the switch boxes, thanks.

Comment: Which fixture did the box in the first photo serve, if any, and which switch in the second and third photos is which?

Comment: The ceiling box in photo 1 is where the hallway light was connected. The switch on the left in photo 2 is for the bedroom overhead light, switch on the right is the 3 way for the hallway light and closet light (these are supposed to come on at the same time). Switch in photo 3 is the other 3 way for the hallway and closet light.

Comment: Which cable is which in the ceiling box pic?

Comment: @Vincent What does the hallway light do currently? Stay on? Stay off?

Comment: The hallway light is the one I’m trying to reconnect to this box. It should be wired in with the closet light to come on and off at the same time. The closet light goes on and off normally (3way) from either switch.

Comment: Can you provide a pic of the closet light (which, it seems, works properly with both 3-way switches)? Also, identify which wire is which in the hallway light pic. There's a lot going on up there...

Comment: @Vincent -- are you trying to run a new cable for the hallway light? I can't figure out which of the wires in the existing ceiling box connect to the hall light to begin with....

Comment: Updated my box photo with labels. I took off the working closet light and it is a black/white wire going to the fixture. I traced this wire back to the ceiling box and the black wire goes to #4, white goes to #1. Red wire in #1 is always hot, black wires in #4 are hot when the light is on. Wired my fixture the same as the wire to the closet light - black to #4 and white to #1 bundle and it works now. When the 3way is off, the hallway light glows very slightly - I can only see this slight glow in the dark. Is this caused by the LED driver storing energy or is this a wiring problem? Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent -- glad you figured it out, post it as an answer and I'll give you a +1 :) BTW: the slight glow of the hallway light is caused by the LED driver being sensitive enough to react to the small amount of current that flows between the travelers due to capacitive coupling between the two (as they're two wires in parallel in the same cable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from my comment as an answer: I took off the working closet light and it is a black/white wire going to the fixture. I traced this wire back to the ceiling box and the black wire goes to #4, white goes to #1. Red wire in #1 is always hot, black wires in #4 are hot when the light is on. Wired my fixture the same as the wire to the closet light - black to #4 and white to #1 bundle and it works now. Thanks!